# Chrome/Sass Sourcemaps, changes made in inspector not saved in SCSS file

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

Here's a quick summary of what I'm talking about:

https://medium.com/what-i-learned-building/b4daab987fb0

When using Chrome with workspaces and sourcemaps set up, and the local/network files linked, I can use the Chrome web inspector (under the Elements -> styles pane) to recognise the location of the selector in the correct SCSS file. In addition, I can click that, be taken to the SCSS file, make a change and then save it successfully to the file system. However, what I have previously had working is changes made in the **elements->styles** panel to get updated in the SCSS file (i.e. If I make a change in the elements tab and check the SCSS file within chrome it should have changed it).

Instead it makes the changes to the CSS file. Obviously this is not very useful as:

- It will be overwritten as soon as the SCSS file is changed
- It means Chrome will show styles which are not in the SCSS file, even after reload, as they *are* saved persistently in the CSS file

I've tried this on both OSX and Windows, using Sass 3.3.6.
Can also confirm that it's not the "../" issue referred to in #9
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=273384 as the sass file is now within the css file. There are also no style.css?ver=x extensions on the stylesheet tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257778 is what you are asking for. Patching SCSS in place of CSS when the Styles pane is edited is impossible (ambiguous) in the general case if variables or complex language features are involved, so your best bet is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the required CSS property in the Styles pane to navigate to the corresponding SCSS fragment and edit plain SCSS resource text, then save (<kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>) and let the sass compiler (running in the watch mode) do the rest. You should have both of the `Enable CSS source maps` and `Auto-reload generated CSS` settings enabled for the DevTools to pick up the generated CSS changes.

Comment: Thanks, accepted. I must have been mistaken when I thought this was working already. It would be a nice feature, nonetheless, for the Styles pane to patch the SCSS when there are only plain CSS styles within that selector and the selector does not use SASS placeholders, etc.

Comment: Is this related to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257778 @alexander-pavlov ? There won't be a workaround for sass to be persisted in styles pane?

Comment: @fernandopasik: This is only tangentially related to the issue you mention. That one is about a generated CSS edit in the Styles pane killing the CSS->SCSS link.

Comment: @fernadopasik its not impossible, see my comments on that issue. Before making any edits, it knew the correct line within the LESS. The problem is when I edit the same line in the inspector vs the source tab, it behaves differently. If its possible to do in the source tab, its possible in the inspector tab. Chrome just needs to fix the glitch.